# Exception when Implementing RPC Security Management in corda using spring webserver

Tags: spring, spring-boot, webserver, rpc, corda

Spring Web server not started when we specify RPC Security Management configuration in node.conf file.

```
Getting error as Unresolved reference: proxy, while running PartyAServer.
```

Below is my server configuration for PartyA node :-

```
task runPartyAServer(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'com.example.server.Server'
    environment "server.port", "10022"
    environment "config.rpc.host", "localhost"
    environment "config.rpc.port", "10006"
}
```

I am able to start the node with following node A configuration, but facing error while running PartyA server.

```
node {
        name "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
        advertisedServices = ["com.example"]
        p2pPort 10005
        rpcPort 10006
        cordapps = ["$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version",
                    "com.example:java-source:$version",
                    "com.example:base:$version"]
    }
```

Below is my node.conf for PartyA node :-

```
extraAdvertisedServiceIds=[
    "com.example"
]
myLegalName="O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
networkMapService {
    address="localhost:10002"
    legalName="O=Controller,L=London,C=GB"
}
p2pAddress="localhost:10005"
rpcAddress="localhost:10006"
rpcUsers=[]
security = {
    authService = {
        dataSource = {
            type = "DB",
            passwordEncryption = "SHIRO_1_CRYPT",
            connection = {
               jdbcUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.16.105.21:1521:SFMS"
               username = "abinay"
               password = "abinay"
               driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
            }
        }
        options = {
             cache = {
                expireAfterSecs = 120
                maxEntries = 10000
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Without having username and password how nodeRPCConnection(proxy) will be established with following code,

```
 @PostConstruct
    public void initialiseNodeRPCConnection() {
        NetworkHostAndPort rpcAddress = new NetworkHostAndPort(host,rpcPort);
        CordaRPCClient rpcClient = new CordaRPCClient(rpcAddress);
        rpcConnection = rpcClient.start(username, password);
        proxy = rpcConnection.getProxy();
        staticMap.put("proxy",proxy);
    }
```

Comment: can we implement RPC security management while using spring webserver in corda, reference link:- https://docs.corda.net/clientrpc.html

Comment: NodeRPCConnection.java, where we define a class that allows an RPC connection to be made to the node

Answer (score 0):

This strikes me as more likely to be an oracle connection issue.

I'd start by writing some java code just to ensure that you can connect to the oracle DB, and then focus on getting that to work in the cordapp environment.

There's a good developer example on this (in both java and kotlin: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Basic/flow-database-access ; https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/tree/master/Basic/flow-database-access)

Best of luck on this!